# Convert multiple partial columns as a one row in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, rownum

I have a table with below structure

```
Student:    Studentno   Studentname Grade    School

               1         aaaaa       3      cambridge
               2         bbbbb       4      edison
               3         ccccc       5      concord

mark:    Studentno   subject mark
            1        maths     55
            1        science   23
            1        history   99
            2        english    89
            2        maths   78
            2        history   100
            3        history     77
            3        science   82
            3        maths   78
```

I need the resultset like below.

```
Studentno Studentname Grade School  subject1 mark1 subject2 mark2 suject3 mark3

   1         aaaaa       3  cambridge maths   55     science  23    history  99
   2         bbbbb       4  edison    english   89    maths  78    history  100
   3         ccccc       5  concord   history   77     science  82 maths  78
```

I used row number, but it displays the rownumber values, but i need in the above format.  Tried Pivot, but not a familiar in that.  Need help

Comment: how many subjects? are they fixed like maths, sciense and history so only 3 of them... either it's not limited... if it's limited - we can use pivot, if not - something more complex

Comment: Subjects are only 3, but the subject might be different.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use *condition aggregate function* after `JOIN` those tables.

`MAX` with `CASE WHEN`

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
   Studentno INT,
   Studentname VARCHAR(50),
   Grade INT,
   School VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Student values (1,'aaaaa',3,'cambridge');
INSERT INTO Student values (2,'bbbbb',4,'edison');
INSERT INTO Student values (3,'ccccc',5,'concord');

CREATE TABLE mark(
   Studentno INT,
   subject VARCHAR(50),
   mark INT
);


insert into mark values (1,'maths',55);
insert into mark values (1,'science',23);
insert into mark values (1,'history',99);
insert into mark values (2,'maths',89);
insert into mark values (2,'science',78);
insert into mark values (2,'history',100);
insert into mark values (3,'maths',77);
insert into mark values (3,'science',82);
insert into mark values (3,'history',78);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT s.STUDENTNO,
       s.Studentname,
       s.Grade,
       s.School,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn= 1 THEN subject END) "subject1",
       MAX(CASE WHEN m.SUBJECT ='maths' THEN m.MARK END)  "Math",
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn= 2 THEN subject END)  "subject2",
       MAX(CASE WHEN m.SUBJECT ='science' THEN m.MARK END)  "science",
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn= 3 THEN subject END)  "subject3",
       MAX(CASE WHEN m.SUBJECT ='history' THEN m.MARK END) "history"
FROM (
  SELECT m.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY STUDENTNO ORDER BY mark) rn
  FROM mark m
) m  
JOIN Student s on m.STUDENTNO = s.STUDENTNO
GROUP BY s.STUDENTNO,
       s.Studentname,
       s.Grade,
       s.School
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7b7b7/27/0)**:

```
| STUDENTNO | STUDENTNAME | GRADE |    SCHOOL | subject1 | Math | subject2 | science | subject3 | history |
|-----------|-------------|-------|-----------|----------|------|----------|---------|----------|---------|
|         1 |       aaaaa |     3 | cambridge |  science |   55 |    maths |      23 |  history |      99 |
|         2 |       bbbbb |     4 |    edison |  science |   89 |    maths |      78 |  history |     100 |
|         3 |       ccccc |     5 |   concord |    maths |   77 |  history |      82 |  science |      78 |
```

Comment: I have corrected the example, The subjects are not consistent

Comment: @user3738664 Is there any column can represent the order for `subject` if not you can't make sure the order,

Comment: The subjects are different for each student. What i need is it should be display in the same row.  Ex: 1st and 2nd student subject is different.

Comment: if you want to make a order need to use `order by` otherwise, it will not make sure the order.

Comment: order is not a matter, only thing is if the subjects are different..  The above solution work only if the subject is same

Comment: @user3738664 If the order is not matter you can try my edit answer.

Comment: Thank you.. i am thinking Pivot also will work out. will try

Answer (score 0):

if there're only 3 subjects you can get marks for each subject via subquery

`SQL`

```
select 
        s.Studentno, s.Studentname, s.Grade, s.School
        ,'maths' as subject1, (select mark from mark m where s.Studentno = m.Studentno and m.subject = 'maths') as mark1
        ,'science' as subject2, (select mark from mark m where s.Studentno = m.Studentno and m.subject = 'science') as mark2
        ,'history' as subject3, (select mark from mark m where s.Studentno = m.Studentno and m.subject = 'history') as mark3
         from Student s
```

`SQL with sample data`

```
with Student as
(
select 1 as Studentno, 'aaaaa' as Studentname, 3 as Grade, 'cambridge' as School from dual union all
select 2 as Studentno, 'bbbbb' as Studentname, 4 as Grade, 'edison' as School from dual union all
select 3 as Studentno, 'ccccc' as Studentname, 5 as Grade, 'concord' as School from dual
),
mark as ( 
select 1 as Studentno, 'maths' as subject, 55 as mark from dual union all
select 1,'science',   23 from dual union all
select 1,'history',   99 from dual union all
select 2,'maths',   89 from dual union all
select 2,'science',   78 from dual union all
select 2,'history',   100 from dual union all
select 3,'maths',   77 from dual union all
select 3,'science',   82 from dual union all
select 3,'history',   78 from dual
)            
select 
s.Studentno, s.Studentname, s.Grade, s.School
,'maths' as subject1, (select mark from mark m where s.Studentno = m.Studentno and m.subject = 'maths') as mark1
,'science' as subject2, (select mark from mark m where s.Studentno = m.Studentno and m.subject = 'science') as mark2
,'history' as subject3, (select mark from mark m where s.Studentno = m.Studentno and m.subject = 'history') as mark3
 from Student s
```

`Result`

```
1   1   aaaaa   3   cambridge   maths   55  science 23  history 99
2   3   ccccc   5   concord maths   77  science 82  history 78
3   2   bbbbb   4   edison  maths   89  science 78  history 100
```

Comment: I have corrected the example, The subjects are not consistent